# JQuery Datatables without Array

Tags: json, datatables

I'm having trouble populating a table, accessing a text file that has JSON like this:

```
{
    "1000": {
        "country": "US",
        "eventid": 1000,
        "venue": "San Francisco, USA"
    },
    "2000": {
        "country": "DE",
        "eventid": 2000,
        "venue": "Munich, Germany"
    },
    "3000": {
        "country": "GB",
        "eventid": 3000,
        "venue": "UK (Market House)"
    }
}
```

I have followed the examples on datatables.net and tried loading it on to my HTML

```
<HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="datatable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Event</th>
                    <th>Venue</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the datatable.js is as simple as this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": 'sample.txt',
        "columns": [
            { "country" },
            { "eventid" },
            { "venue" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Can someone help me figure out where I have gone wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by adding a custom function as part of dataSrc attribute (Thanks Jongyu Lin). Here is the change to my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": 'json.txt',
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                var arr = Object.keys(json).map(function(k) { return json[k] });
                return arr;
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [2],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": true
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "eventid"
            },
            {
                "data": "country"
            },
            {
                "data": "venue"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: +1. It is a very good solution, now you dont have the possibility for changing the source. You should mark your answer as accepted, when you are able to, perhaps helping other people in the future.