# Bootstrap data server side processing - data not displayed

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am new to python flask development. I am trying to implement a server side processing data table which will fetch records from a mysql database table with 1000's of records.

I want the table to display 10 rows per page and query the server/ database for each new page or search.

This is my HTML -

```
 <div class="dataTable_wrkld">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-wrkld">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <!--<th class="bs-checkbox-1"></th>-->
                                <th data-align="center">ID</th>
                                <th data-align="center">Name</th>
                                <th data-align="center">Total Items</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
 </div>
```

This is my script -

```
<!-- DATA TABLES -->
<script>
    var table_data = ''
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-wrkld').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                url: '/datatable_change',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function ( args ) {
                         return { "args": JSON.stringify( args ) };
                },
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                        var arr = Object.keys(json).map(function(k) { return json[k] });
                        return arr;
                },
                columns: [
                {"data": "ID"},
                {"data": "Name"},
                {"data": "Items"}
                ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

On the server side I have -

```
    @app.route('/datatable_change', methods=['POST'])
def datatable_change():
    abc = json.loads(request.values.get("args"))
    temp = session.query(Table.id, Table.name, table.total_items).limit(100)
    data = Utilities.make_json_dict(['ID', 'Name', 'Items'], temp)
    print(json.dumps(data))
    return json.dumps(data)
```

When I run it, the break point is hit and get the data from DB. This is how my json looks like -

```
[
{"Items": 31, "ID": 1, "Name": "abc"}, 
{"Items": 35, "ID": 2, "Name": "def"}, 
{"Items": 38, "ID": 3, "Name": "ghi"}
.
.
.
]
```

I used this answer to format my data source -
[Format ajax dats src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568942/jquery-datatables-without-array)

If I don't use this, I get a "Could not read property 'length' of undefined.." Jquery error

After running this all,
This is the error i get -

[image]

And on clicking OK, this is how my data table looks like -

[image]

Notice that is not responding to the pagination. I don't get any errors in browser console.
What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: You have comma missing before `columns: [`

Comment: Edited to add the comma; missed it while constructing the question - this is not the problem, though.

Comment: Can you please add `console.log(JSON.stringify(json));` in `dataSrc` just before `return arr;` and post the results?

Comment: getting this - [{"Items":31,"ID":1,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":35,"ID":2,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":38,"ID":3,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":25,"ID":4,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":44,"ID":5,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":35,"ID":6,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":28,"ID":7,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":41,"ID":8,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":33,"ID":9,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":26,"ID":10,"Name":"ABC"},
{"Items":44,"ID":11,"Name":"ABC"},

...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work with server side processing. On the html side, the error was as mentioned by Gyrocode.com in his answer. But I changed the serverSide: True and also the format of the data returned.

On the server side, there is python module which takes care of the necessary table events -
[python datatables module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datatables/0.4.1)

However this module has been written for python pyramid framework. A few minor changes were required to get it to work with flask.

Here is the final code -

```
$('#dataTables-server').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                  url: '/datatable_change',
                  method: 'post',
                  data: function(args) {
                    return {
                      "args": JSON.stringify(args)
                    };
                  }
                },
                columns: [

                  { "data": "ID" },
                  { "data": "Name" },
                  { "data": "Items" }
                ]
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

> **CAUSE**

Option [`columns`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) should not be sub-property of [`ajax`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax), so there is closing bracket `}` missing.

Also your returned JSON is structured for client-side mode so you need to set `serverSide: false`. In server-side processing mode, you need to do sorting, filtering and ordering on the server-side and the returned data need to have [certain structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data).

Based on your data structure, option [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) should be set to empty string, i.e. `dataSrc: ""`.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckf214xp/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to display to data by changing the columns options. I also modified it to work with server side processing, however, the table does not respond to pagination and search. Can you tell me what needs to be done here?